# Integer representation of Samsung remote keycodes

Tags: upnp, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to send key codes to a samsung smart tv using UPnP. I found the list of available key codes [here](http://wiki.samygo.tv/index.php5/D-Series_Key_Codes). But How can i represent the same in integer, because samsung wants to receive this as integer values in the UPnP services.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have manual way. So pressing any button on remote give you info what `int` value it has:

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
  alert("You pressed: " + keyCode);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply. I am trying to sendkeycode from my android phone. I think this piece of code is to be implemented as a samsung smart tv app right? How can I do this code? Can you please give some inputs. Thanks

Comment: Here you have info how to create your first app: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_3.5/Getting_Started/Application_Development_Process/Implementing_Your_Application_Code/Coding_Your_JavaScript_Application You need to add jQuery, and then paste my code snippet somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the emulator to get a list of the key codes:

```
tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue()
for(key in tvKey) {
  alert(key+": "+tvKey[key]);
}
```

Not a great solution, but might work for your purposes.